# What is the dual space to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Tags: algebraic-topology, modules, homological-algebra, dual-spaces

I understand that $(\mathbb{Z}^n)^* = \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n, \mathbb{Z})$. But is there a generic description or more intuitive isomorphism for that space? I'm trying to use Hungerford as a reference, but it doesn't seem to help with trying to calculate what the dual space is.

This is stemming from looking at something in homological algebra. So we have a chain complex.
$C_n\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow C_0$ and each $C_i$ is a free abelian group (or $\mathbb Z$-module) with $n_i$ generators. We $\hom(-,\mathbb{Z})$ everything and end up with $$\hom(C_0,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow \hom(C_n, \mathbb{Z}).$$ I'm interested in understanding the derived functor $\operatorname{Ext}^i$ and it seems like understanding the hom-group is the first step to that.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are looking for, but $f \in \mathrm{Hom}(\Bbb{Z}^n, \Bbb{Z})$ is uniquely determined by $f(e_1), \ldots, f(e_n)$ where the $e_i$ form the standard basis (or any basis) for $\Bbb{Z}^n$. From this you should be able to see that $ \mathrm{Hom}(\Bbb{Z}^n, \Bbb{Z})$ is the free$\Bbb{Z}$-module on the basis $f_i$, where $f_i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$ (where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)).

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are looking for, but maybe this is helpful: A homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ is the same thing as a collection of $n$ homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ (this is the "universal property of direct sums" -- to go from a collection of homomorphisms to one from $\mathbb{Z}^n$, just add them up over the $n$ coordinates).  A homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself is determined by the image of $1$ and is therefore given by the data of a single element of $\mathbb{Z}$. So in the end you find that this hom set is iso. to $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: Again I don't know what kind of background you have in these things in algebra -- if you haven't seen it before it might help to look at the material on dual spaces of vector spaces in Axler's book "Linear Algebra Done Right," and in particular about the dual basis. Here you are dealing with free modules over a ring so linear algebra over a field is enough to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks! This answers it! I have no real experience in this field. I was hoping there would be some interesting structure or information here, but since they are isomorphic, the homologies will also be isomorphic.

Comment: Be careful with homology: you have to dualize the maps, too. Torsion in homology in dimension $n$ should lead to torsion in the homology of the dual complex in dimension $n+1$. The Universal Coefficient Theorem is the relevant result.

Comment: What does this question have to do with functional analysis?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri The set of linear functionals in vector spaces is Hom(V, k) for k the field you are working over. I assumed people who do functional analysis also study the structure of this space. A quick google search for functional analysis shows that pretty much every course on functional analysis covers functionals and duality, the very thing I am asking about except over modules and rings.

Comment: I'm guessing John's question was rather rhetorical, this has nothing to do with functional analysis because in functional analysis we never work over $\mathbb{Z}$ (functional analysis is mainly about Banach spaces after all).

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I don't know anything. I was just trying to explain why I thought it fell into functional analysis. I still think there's no reason to think functional analysis only operates over fields. https://www.elsevier.com/books/topics-in-functional-analysis-over-valued-division-rings/prolla/978-0-444-86535-9 for instance. It may not be normal to do it, but it isn't impossible.